# Clustered Nifi running erratically,the issue often appear

Tags: apache-nifi

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

[image]
[image]
[image]

3 NODE,Nifi-1.10.0,ZK-3.6.5

i reset the relevant setting to make Nifi to respond in given time as following.But this ways can't work!?

```
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=120 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=120 sec
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=30 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=30 secs

nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=30 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=30 secs

nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec
```

UPDATED:
While enter NIFI UI,Nifi can't running.There are only an app in this VM.

3 Node has same spec and configuration

java.arg.2=-Xms4g
java.arg.3=-Xmx4g

[image]

NIFI-APP.LOG

```
2020-06-03 08:54:27,845 WARN [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager Session timeout has elapsed while SUSPENDED. Injecting a session expiration. Elapsed ms: 32546. Adjusted session timeout ms: 30000
```

ZK-LOG

```
2020-06-02 18:12:45,232 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-5:NIOServerCnxn@366] - Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1014019b26f0005, likely client has closed socket
```

Comment: Edit post with node spec (core/ram) and the Nifi Configs min/max ram settings.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz Thank u your response.I've updated as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kong a few things to consider:

1. Set your min max at 4g and 8g,  work up to 60-70% of the total ram of the node.  Restart Nifi often to reset ram stolen from memory leaks.  Restart all before adjusting for performance.
2. Check your max thread tuning.  This needs to be based on the number of cores you have.  Default settings will not make full use of the node cores.
3. Adjust Garbage Collection - there are quite a few posts around with info on what to do here.
4. Inspect flow for bad concurrency or schedule settings.  A processor on the wrong schedule (0 sec for example), or with large concurrency can create instability.

I suspect you have a small combination of settings to adjust and you should see the stability you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.Does the huge JVM of Nifi would make NIFI UI stuck?Suspect other servers don't have enough resource to run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the memory of JVM is too much,so that VM isn't enough for performance to make the Zookeeper work.

Tune JVM to 2G,the Nifi can work successfully.

Comment: Negative sir.  It looks like there is not much available ram.   Nifi will take more than just the min max settings.    I will make a comment/answer with some next steps.